# Are the Sentinel-2 images in Google Earth Engine already topographically corrected?

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-2, topography, sen2cor

I'd like to know if the Sentinel-2 Level-2A imagery, hosted in Google Earth Engine, was processed to attenuate topographic effects.

The dataset description page (https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/COPERNICUS_S2_SR) informs us that the images went into the **sen2cor** algorithm. I know that **Topographic Correction** in **sen2cor** is optional. So, I found nothing in GEE informing if the scenes were processed to perform both atmospheric correction and topography correction. Does anyone know it?

Comment: This question is more suited for the s2tbx forum: https://forum.step.esa.int/c/s2tbx/6

As far as I know, ESA does not document exactly how sen2cor was run.

Comment: @SimonIlyushchenko, as far as I know, topographic correction is an optional step in sen2cor algorithm. So it depends on if the GEE S2_SR assets have been topographically corrected via the GEE processing workflow. Anyway, thank you for commenting.